# Connection Formula - Current and Previous Member

Tags: filter, connection, dashboard-designer-2013

I am using SharePoint 2013 and PerformancePoint Dashboard Designer 2013. 
I have a Filter and a Chart in a Dashboard Page. When I select a member in a Filter, I want the Chart to display data for Current Member and one Previous Member.

In the Connection Formula Dialogue, I used following two formulas but it only displays data for Current Member only in both cases.

```
LastPeriods
(2,
 {<<SourceValue>>}.item(0)
)
```

And

```
LastPeriods
(2,
 {<<UniqueName>>}.item(0)
)
```

[image]

Please correct me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LastPeriods
{2,
<<UniqueItem>>
}
```

worked for me.